# Setting the minimum, maximum and default length of a grid column / row

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm aware of the new [`minmax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) function that allows specification of minimum and maximum width for a grid column. When using this function, however, I'm unclear what the "default" width of the column would be, and how to specify it.

Outside of a grid - including in flex layouts - it's possible to specify something like this:

```
.container {
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

effectively creating a container that would by default occupy 25% of its parent's width, but never shrink below 200px or grow past 400px.

What's the grid equivalent way of achieving this effect?

Answer (score 4):

Based on your general CSS code sample...

```
.container {
    width: 25%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

here's one approach that may work in CSS Grid:

1. Set the width of the first column to a minimum of 200px and a maximum of 400px.
2. Set the width of the second column to a minimum of 75% and a maximum of `1fr`.

The 75% on the second column forces the first column to be 25%.

The `1fr` enables the second column to consume extra space.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 400px) minmax(75%, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#container > div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    grid item<br> minimum width = 200px<br> maximum width = 400px
  </div>
  <div>
    grid item<br> minimum width = 75%<br> maximum width = 1fr
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9mdpnemk/2/)

Notes:

- More columns can be added. They just need to have widths that collectively add up to 75%.
- You may need to deal with an overflow condition, depending on your exact situation.
- There aren't many details about the layout in your question, so I can't be more precise.

Aside from the solution above, I don't believe this effect is possible with CSS Grid.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to say:

> *The column width must be 25% of the container and never less than 200px or more than 400px.*

You can either set the `minmax()` or the fixed length.

In other words, you can do this:

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 400px);
}
```

... or this:

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25%;
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px, 400px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}

#container > div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    grid item<br> minimum width = 200px<br> maximum width = 400px
  </div>
  <div>
    grid item<br> takes remaining space on the row
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9mdpnemk/)

Depending on your exact circumstances, setting the container to 25% and min-max to the grid item, may work for you. Something like this:

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25%;
}

#container > div {
   min-width: 200px;
   max-width: 400px;
}
```

**Just keep in mind** that the first rule sizes the *column* and the second rule sizes the *grid item*. So there may be times (especially on wider screens) when the 25% column is wider than the 400px grid item. This would result in a gap.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}

#container > div:first-child {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
}

#container > div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    grid item
    <br> minimum width = 200px
    <br> maximum width = 400px
  </div>
  <div>
    grid item
    <br> takes remaining space on the row
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9mdpnemk/1)

Comment: Thanks Michael. While creative, I think this is a somewhat unintuitive/roundabout way of setting a column's desired width, having to carefully craft its adjacent columns' widths. I imagine lacking the ability to simultaneously define the trio of [width, min-width, and max-width] can hinder transitioning from a flex-layout (where this is trivial) to grids. Have you come across anything in the specs or examples by any chance that may indicate other solutions?

Comment: For some effects, flexbox may have the advantage. No surprise there. Flex and Grid are two different technologies.