# Two-Column grid should wrap into One-Column grid

Tags: css, css-grid

In my css grid I have one large item in the left column and three smaller items in the right column:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: black;
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.item-2,
.item-3,
.item-4 {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-4 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
  <div class="item-4"></div>
</div>
```

Now on smaller screens the three items on the right just disappear and only the black one is visible. This is because I have declared exactly 3 rows in `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 200px);`, correct?

What I want however is that all 4 items wrap under each other (e.g. the grid should have 1 column and 6 rows):

[image: Desired result]

I know that this could be reached using media queries, but I wanted to avoid those in this scenario if possible.

I have tried `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 200px)` but this didn't provide the desired result.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: *"Now on smaller screens the three items on the right just disappear and only the black one is visible. This is because I have declared exactly 3 rows in `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 200px)`, correct?"* No. That's not correct.

Comment: The right column disappears because it has no content inside and no defined width. Therefore, once the browser window shrinks below 600px (based on `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))`, and a two-column grid), the second column just collapses to 0 width.

Comment: If even one grid item in the second column had some kind of width, you would see it. http://jsfiddle.net/9og5d6zt/2

Comment: In terms of shifting to a vertical layout on smaller screens, if a media query is not an option, how is the browser supposed to know to make the transition?

Comment: My hope was that I could make the grid switch to a vertical layout once the two columns (minimal width 300px) don't fit next to each other anymore.

Comment: Understood. I don't think you can accomplish that with Grid. However, `flex-wrap` in flexbox *may* be useful to you: https://jsfiddle.net/4breog3k/

Comment: Keep in mind that the layout you want is not possible in Grid because you have specified the position of items using line-based placement (e.g., `grid-row: span 3`). If you leave the items to flow naturally, they would wrap as you expect. https://jsfiddle.net/am3Lr5fh/

Comment: Yes, a possible approach would be to treat the two columns as two items of a flexbox with `flex-wrap`. However, I am trying to accomplish that behavior with a grid and not introduce wrappers for the items.

Comment: hm, I am using `grid-row: span 3` to give the black item three times the height of the other ones. In your fiddle (jsfiddle.net/am3Lr5fh) this is unfortunately not the case anymore and all four items have the same height :(

Comment: I'm aware of that. The purpose of that fiddle was to illustrate the only way `auto-fit` and `auto-fill` could work. Using `grid-row: span 3` disables the functions.

Answer (score -1):

you could try

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'a a';
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 50px);
    grid-auto-flow: column; 
}
```

3 Black Lines - 3 color lines

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .container {
     grid-template-areas: 'a';
     grid-template-columns: 100%;
     grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 50px);
   }
}
```

1 Black line and 3 Color lines

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .container {
     grid-template-areas: 'a';
     grid-template-columns: 100%;
     grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 50px);
   }

  .item-1 {
    grid-row: span 1;
  }
}
```

You can set the width for the media query as you want.

Comment: Seems like this does not make the columns wrap, it just keeps the three colored items right of the black one. Or did you also change the css for the items?

Comment: Thank you. I know that it is possible with media queries. However I was looking for a way to achieve this without media queries.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid media queries is that the breakpoints need to be calculated in dependence of the constants used to create the grid. I was hoping that css-grid provides a cleaner solution that does not require such dependencies. Articles like [this](https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/) demonstrate the responsive power of css grids without media queries, however I could not figure out how to apply such techniques to my scenario.

Comment: I understand. Grids and Flex boxes are powerful but the structure can not be that dynamic. The responsiveness of the given structure, can be. Without media queries it will be harder. The given structure..You want them to be 1-3 which means you want them to behave like a column at first and wrap after. To change the current structure like that  you'll need media queries. If you change your HTML structure you will achieve it. Let's say if you wrap these 3 color divs  in a parent div, then you'll have two main elements to position and play around.