# How to get the effect of grid layout's grid-template-columns with a variable number of columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a div containing a variable number of children. This code is generated and I can't modify it. So with only CSS I need to display divs in a table with two rows:

- The first row contains only the first div (100% width)
- The other div share the second row : each div will have the same width an the should totally fill the row.

I tried with a grid layout + grid-template-columns but using grid-template-columns does not because because it supposes I know the number of columns. For example, the following snippet only works if there are 4 children

```css
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

```html
Test with 3 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;" >
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
</div>
Test with 4 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;" >
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
</div>
Test with 5 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;" >
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:purple;">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can do what I think you are after

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.child {
  flex: 1;
  padding: .25em 0;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.25em;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

```html
Test with 3 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
</div>
Test with 4 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
</div>
Test with 5 children
<div class="parent" style="background-color:yellow;">
  <div class="child" style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:blue;">2</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:orange;">4</div>
  <div class="child" style="background-color:purple;">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually it's exactly what I need : because or flex-wrap, the items may wrap on a 3rd row. I'd like to keep only 2 rows

Comment: I meant it's *not* exactly what I need

Comment: @jaudo so at the end, it's what you need or not?

Answer (score -2):

EDIT:

I thought this would work:

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.child:first-child {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.child:not(:first-child) {
  grid-row: 2;
}
```

However, it seems that `grid-column: 1 / -1` does not work for auto-columns. That is very unfortunate. Therefore, the best route here would be to use flexbox, as already pointed out.

---

*Previous answer*

You should be able to solve that like this:

```
.parent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}
```

The key there is `grid-auto-flow` which will establish that any unforeseen elements will be added as extra columns. With `grid-auto-columns` you can specify the default size of the automatically added columns.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, unfortunately, it does not work as I thought it would. I edited the answer accordingly.