# Filling cells starting from the bottom in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with 3 rows. There may be less than 3 items to fill it, and I want to start filling it from the bottom.

I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lexogram/vd7g4x5e/8/) for you to play with, but it currently fails to do what I want.

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  /* MISSING RULE */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Last item</p>
  <p>Second last item</p>
  <p>Top item</p>
</div>
```

Actual output:

```
Last item
Second last item
Top item
```

Desired output:

```
Top item
Second last item
Last item
```

I'd like to apply one rule to the `<div>` that contains the grid, rather than separate rules to the items in the grid, if that is possible.

Comment: Are you set on using `grid` properties? This can be done with flexbox in two lines.

Comment: @TylerH: Actually, there are multiple columns, so a flexbox solution would require more complex HTML.

Comment: Can you update your code here to include what another column may look like?

Answer (score -1):

There is no [`column-reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) function in [CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), like there is in flexbox.

Therefore, getting grid areas to populate a container starting from the bottom isn't possible with a single rule in the container.

Here's how it would work in flexbox:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  height: 100vh;
}

p {
  flex: 1;
}


/* demo styles */
p {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
p + p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Last item</p>
  <p>Second last item</p>
  <p>Top item</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use CSS Grid layout it will be like this. I modify your HTML. You have to write CSS property for grid child item where to start and where to end. `grid-row-start:` and `grid-row-end:`. [Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/WNvBjvP).

```css
  .grid-item{
      border: 2px solid red;
      border-radius: 5px;
      height: 200px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 300px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
    .grid-item p{
      margin: 0;
    }
    .grid-item .first-item{
      grid-row-start: 1;
    }
    .grid-item .last-item{
      grid-row-start: 3;
    }
```

```html
<div class="grid-item">
        <p class="last-item">Last item</p>
        <p class="second-item">Second last item</p>
        <p class="first-item">Top item</p>
    </div>
```

If you want to use `flexbox` it will be using **two** line code.

```
<div>
    <p>Last item</p>
    <p>Second last item</p>
    <p>Top item</p>
</div>
```

**CSS** for this

```
div{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

The [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) CSS property sets how flex items are placed in the flex container defining the main axis and the direction (normal or reversed).

Comment: OP says the number of items is dynamic so you won't know how to apply the `n-item` classes.