# Using CSS grid how do i make a one column layout where one element fills remaining space after all others have taken an auto width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

1. I don't want to explicitly define the number of columns so i can add other auto width children to it later.
2. I don't want to use extra wrappers.
3. I want to do it in CSS grid not flexbox (I can do it in flexbox with wrappers and all)
4. In case you are wondering its a layout for a navigation bar

   [Heres what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHqKd.png)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.item--1,
.item--3 {
  grid-column: 1fr;
  width: 100px;
}

.item--2 {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container-1 {
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  }
  .item--1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
  }
  .item--2 {
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
  }
  .item--3 {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item--1"></div>
  <div class="item item--2">Fill up remaining space</div>
  <div class="item item--3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this isn't better than your old question where you at least had code (https://stackoverflow.com/q/62044990/8620333) .. here this is no question but only a list of requirements

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry man, my bad

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't want flexbox for this? you can do it with flexbox and without extra wrapper

Comment: @TemaniAfif could you help me out with that, like with some code
also grid because that question is just stuck in my head

Comment: you won't find any clean code using CSS grid if the number of elements isn't known and the element that need to fill the space isn't known too. Flexbox is more suitable here

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
Thanks for the answer,
Hope you understand what i am trying to learn here with grid,
In case you find it please post it

Comment: learning is a thing and trying to do *impossible* stuff is another thing ... you can learn to drive a car but you cannot use your car to fly. You should learn to use the best tool for each case instead of trying to overcomplicate something. read this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif to be able do that in grid seemed so amazing, it could have been so much cleaner and understandable

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with flexbox and without extra wrapper:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* this is your gap */
.item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
/**/

.fill {
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  flex-grow: 1; /* fill the remaining space */
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow the wrap */
  }
  .fill {
    order: 2; /* make the element the last on*/
    flex-basis: 100%; /* 100% width */
    margin-right: 0!important;
  }
  .fill + * {
    margin-left: auto; /* keep the element on the left */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item fill">Fill up remaining space</div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```