# CSS Grid (or) Flex for two rows with 4 and 3 columns

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Help, please with this grid. I need to do this using css grid or flex.
Now I have

[image]

But I need this:

[image]

Help please, how to build columns like as in the last screenshot? Thanks in advance!

```css
.grid {
    display:grid;
}
.cols-4 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);   
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="grid cols-4">
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post code that you have so far? From this I can only tell... try using `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` on second row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/3597276

Answer (score 0):

I used Bootstrap just to make same layout like you have.... Only thing important for you is class called `two`... I recommend to do something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row two m-3">
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="w-25 border p-3">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.two{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

You can use `class="two"` on both rows.... it depends on your needs.
[image: Example]

**EDIT 1:**

```css
.flex-rows{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-rows div{
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="flex-rows">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-rows">
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
      <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: No, I dont use bootstrap on this site.

Comment: You don't need to use Bootstrap... I used it only to imitate the same grid....

Comment: Oh... I understand. Thanks. I will use this if no other solutions are offered.

Comment: I edited answer... check it...