# Centering Grid Items last row

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, css-grid, elementor

I am working on a clients website and I have succesfully done this before but ONLY with one item. Now I am working on a grid with 43 elements in columns of 4. The last row has 3 items which I'd like centered. [See here](http://graphicb7.sg-host.com/all-brands/).

I have been stuck on this issue for a while and I belive I am just simply not understanding how the last child/n-th child relationship works

I have used THIS code before to center a singular item

`selector .e-loop-item:last-child:nth-child(3n + 2) {​ grid-column-end: 3; }`

Now I have tried code like

`selector .e-loop-item:last-child:(41)(3n + 1) { grid-column-end: 11; }`

`selector .e-loop-item:last-child(42):nth-child(3n + 2) { grid-column-end: 11; }`

`selector .e-loop-item:last-child(43):nth-child(3n + 2) { grid-column-end: 11; }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55064488/3597276